# Error LNK1561: entry point must be defined- main() exists

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I know that this question has been posted elsewhere, and I've tried those solutions, but I get the error LNK1561 and have no clue where it is causing a problem. This program calculates and prints the largest, smallest, average, and sum of a sequence of numbers the user enters. Any questions or if you need more info, ask.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <climits>
    using namespace std;

    template <class T>
    T dataSet(T &sum, T &largest, T &smallest, T avg);

    template <class T>
    int main(){
        cout << "This program calculates and prints the largest, smallest,"
             << endl << "average, and sum of a sequence of numbers the user enters." << endl;
        T avg, sum, largest, smallest;
        avg = dataSet(&sum, &largest, &smallest, avg);
        cout << "The largest of the sequence you entered is: " << largest << endl;
        cout << "The smallest of the sequence you entered is: " << smallest << endl;
        cout << "The sum of the sequence you entered is: " << largest << endl;
        cout << "The average of the sequence you entered is: " << avg << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    template <class T>
    T dataSet(T &sum, T &largest, T &smallest, T avg){
        T num;
        signed long long int max = LLONG_MIN, min = LLONG_MAX; 
        int count;
        do{
            cout << "Enter a sequence of numbers: (^Z to quit) ";
            cin >> num;
            if(cin.good()){
                count++;
                sum += num;
                if(num > max)
                    max = num;
                if(num < min)
                    min = num
            }
            else if(!cin.good()){
                cout << "Error. Try Again.";
            }
        }while(!cin.eof());
        avg = sum / count;
        return avg;
    }
```

Comment: Which language ? (looks like C++ on DOS to me)

Comment: sorry c++ in visual studio 2012 express

Comment: Your code could generate many different kind of programs.  The C++ language however insists that you only create one.  The linker can't decide which one you want.

Answer (score 1):

`main()` can‘t be a template. You‘ll have to drop the `template <class T>` line before it, and instantiate the `dataSet` using a specific type such as `double`, for example:

```
// No template <class T line>
int main(){
    cout << "This program calculates and prints the largest, smallest,"
         << endl << "average, and sum of a sequence of numbers the user enters." << endl;
    double avg, sum, largest, smallest;
    avg = dataSet(sum, largest, smallest, avg);
…
```

Comment: Is there a way I can keep dataSet as a generic function, while main being an int or void? If not, how else could I return the values outputed in main without using reference?